# Trying to run an offbrand raspberry pi via a direct ethernet connection to PC

Tags: linux, networking, lan, raspberry-pi

I'm working with an off brand Raspberry Pi (BTT Manta M8P/CB1) and the environment I'm working in requires it be directly connected to the PC via an ethernet cable. (Wifi or ethernet connection to router are not possible)

However, when I do this, the interface of the server it's running is often not viewable and the SSH connection keeps breaking. I remember trying this with a Raspberry Pi in the past and there was no issues seeing Mainsail and SSH worked.

Has anyone experienced this or does anyone know what could be different in an off brand Raspberry Pi to cause this? I noticed the device seems to be working when it has an IPV4 address. But it only holds it for a few minutes, and I can tell it lost it when everything starts breaking.

Comment: What is the network configuration on the Manta and on the machine it is connected to?

Comment: The "off-brand Pi" part being the CB1, I assume, not the M8P?... Are non-router Ethernet switches also ruled out, or just routers specifically? Do you happen to have another Ethernet interface (e.g. a USB Ethernet adapter) to test against? Does the PC still report Ethernet link 'up' when the connection dies? Does the BTT Manta report anything on its serial console (if it has one)? Does the device remain reachable on its IPv6 address (it'll likely have at least a link-local fe80:: address)?